# MongoDb performance slow even using index

Tags: mongodb, notifications, indexing, performance

We are trying to build a notification application for our users with mongo. we created 1 mongodb  on 10GB RAM, 150GB SAS HDD 15K RPM, 4 Core 2.9GHZ xeon intel XEN VM.

DB schema :-

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5178c458e4b0e2f3cee77d47"),
  "userId" : NumberLong(1574631),
  "type" : 2,
  "text" : "a user connected to B",
  "status" : 0,
  "createdDate" : ISODate("2013-04-25T05:51:19.995Z"),
  "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2013-04-25T05:51:19.995Z"),
  "metadata" : "{\"INVITEE_NAME\":\"2344\",\"INVITEE\":1232143,\"INVITE_SENDER\":1574476,\"INVITE_SENDER_NAME\":\"123213\"}",
  "opType" : 1,
  "actorId" : NumberLong(1574630),
  "actorName" : "2344"
}

DB stats :-
db.stats()
{
    "db" : "UserNotificationDev2",
    "collections" : 3,
    "objects" : 78597973,
    "avgObjSize" : 489.00035699393925,
    "dataSize" : 38434436856,
    "storageSize" : 41501835008,
    "numExtents" : 42,
    "indexes" : 2,
    "indexSize" : 4272393328,
    "fileSize" : 49301946368,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

index :- userid and _id

we are trying to select latest 21 notifications for one user.

```
db.userNotification.find({ "userId" : 53 }).limit(21).sort({ "_id" : -1 });
```

but this query is taking too much time.
Fri Apr 26 05:39:55.563 [conn156] query UserNotificationDev2.userNotification query: { query: { userId: 53 }, orderby: { _id: -1 } } cursorid:225321382318166794 ntoreturn:21 ntoskip:0 nscanned:266025 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 2 locks(micros) r:4224498 nreturned:21 reslen:10295 2581ms

even count is taking hell lot of time.

```
Fri Apr 26 05:47:46.005 [conn159] command UserNotificationDev2.$cmd command: { count: "userNotification", query: { userId: 53 } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 11 locks(micros) r:9753890 reslen:48 5022ms
```

Are we doing some wrong in the query?

Please help!!!

Also suggest if our schema is not correct to storing user notifications. we have tried a embedded notifications like user and then notification for that user under that document but document limit is limiting us to store only ~50k notifications. so we changed to this.

Comment: Can you run `explain()` on your find, particularly `db.userNotification.find({ "userId" : 53 })`

Comment: Can you run getIndexes() too?

Answer (score 3):

You are querying by userId but not indexing it anywhere. My suggestion is to create an index on `{ "userId" : 1, "_id" : -1 }`. This will create an index tree that starts with userId, then _id, which is almost exactly what your query is doing. This is the simplest/most flexible way to speeding up your query.

Another, more memory efficient, approach is to store your userId and timestamp as a string in _id, like `_id : "USER_ID:DATETIME`. Ex :

```
{_id : "12345:20120501123000"}
{_id : "15897:20120501124000"}
{_id : "15897:20120501125000"}
```

Notice _id is a string, not MongoId. Then your query above becomes a regex :

```
db.userNotification.find({ "_id" : /^53:/ }).limit(21).sort({ "_id" : -1 });
```

As expected, this will return all notifications for userId 53 in descending order. The memory efficient part is two fold:

1. You only need one index field. (Indexes compete with data for memory and are often several gigs in size)
2. If your queries are often about fetching newer data Right Balanced indexes keep your most often working in memory when the indexes are too large to fit whole.

Re: count. Count does take time because it scans through the entire collection.

Re: your schema. I'm guessing for your data set this is the best way to utilize your memory. When objects get large and your queries scan across multiple objects they will need to be loaded into memory in their entirety (I've had the OOM killer kill my mongod instance when i sorted with 2000 2MB objects on a 2GB RAM machine). With large objects your RAM usage will fluctuate greatly (not to mention they are limited upto a point). With your current schema mongo will have a much easier time loading only the data you're querying, resulting in less swapping and more consistent memory usage patterns.

Comment: this is not quite correct. count will use an index. and storing a single field that's as large as two fields in a compound index will not really save you very much and you lose the ability to use that index for sorting.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - Thanks for the info. To my knowledge, in < Mongodb 2.2 a plain count (db.collection.count()) did not use indexes (it wasn't very fast), unless this behavior has improved in 2.4. A count with a sub-query is just like find.

Re: { "userId" : 1, "_id" : -1 }. Point taken. I should have clarified that part of the answer was meant to solve the Op's query in the most obvious way.

Comment: they were using indexes even before 2.4 but not in an efficient way. Imagine performance difference between traversing and reading the entries in the index b-tree between certain ranges, vs just counting how many of them there are.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try sharding then you can distribute notifications evenly between shards so when you need to select you will scan smaller subset of data. Need to decide however what your sharding will be using. To me it looks like operationType or userName but I do not know your data well enough. Another thing is why do you sort by _id?

Comment: Because I need recent inserted notifications of the user

Comment: sharding is not the answer when they don't have optimal indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to replicate your problem. Created 140.000.000 inserts in userNotifications.
Without index on userId I got responses of 3-4seconds. After I created index on userId time dropped to almost instant responses.

```
db.userNotifications.getIndexes()
```

[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.userNotifications",
        "name" : "*id*"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "userId" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.userNotifications",
        "name" : "userId_1"
    }
]

Another thing is: When your select happens is system writing constantly to mongo userNotification collection? Mongo locks whole collection if that happens. If it is the case
I would split read and writes between master and slave (see replication) and also do some sharding. Btw. What language you use for your app?

Comment: you can't "split" reads and writes between primary and secondary because secondary has to do exactly as many writes as the primary.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that you currently don't seem to have an index to support the query for user's latest notifications.

You need a compound index on userId, _id.  This will support queries which only query by userId, but they also are used by queries by userId which sort/limit by _id.

When you add {userId:1, _id:-1} index don't forget to drop index on just userId as it will become redundant.

As far as count() make sure you are using 2.4.3 (the latest version) there were significant improvements in how count() uses indexes which resulted in much better performance.